# using self.navigationController.view in another class Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm currently using MRProgress in my project. Before time, I've put these two libraries in every files of my project. At that time, MRProgress working well and show correctly display in this project. Now I'm creating common class and put all of functions into that class to make reusable and optimize my project like that.

**common.m**

```
- (void) myFuntion:(UIViewController *)myvc {
    [MRProgressOverlayView showOverlayAddedTo:myvc.navigationController.view animated:YES];
    ..
    ..
    ..
    ..
    [MRProgressOverlayView dismissOverlayForView:myvc.navigationController.view animated:YES];
}
```

**myusage.m**

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"stb" bundle:nil];
ViewController *searchVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
[common myFuntion:searchVC];
```

At that time, my problem is **MRProgress cannot display anymore**. Please let me know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First, verify if ViewController is embedded into a navigation controller

> You can put a breakpoint and then 'po searchVC.navigationController' in the console

Btw, I don't know if you did it wrong or not, but it doesn't make sense to add MRProgress on the navigationController and then dismiss it with 'self.view'. You should dismiss the same view you added the overlay, in your example it should be : myvc.navigationController.view

Comment: sorry, it's myvc.navigationController.

Comment: Did you check if your view controller was embedded into a navigation controller ? HEre's a screenshot of what it should looks in the storyboard : http://i.stack.imgur.com/qYdlr.png If you cannot embedded in your navigation controller you should add your overlay to myvc.view instead of myvc.navigationController.view

Answer (score 0):

From above shared code it appears like you have declared instance level method:

```
- (void) myFuntion:(UIViewController *)myvc
```

And you are calling it like class level method, try replacing above prototype with following

```
+ (void) myFuntion:(UIViewController *)mivc
```

Actually methods that are declared with "-" are treated as instance level and functions with "+" are class level.
Reference: http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/classes

Answer (score 0):

Use this method after pushing view like :

```
SceondViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SceondViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
[self myFuntion:controller];
```

Hope it will useful for you.